# Correct value for $state.go from window.location.hash

Tags: angularjs

My following js is valid as a part of AngularJS snippet:

```
window.location.hash = "#!/details/"+id;
```

What would be the correct code using `$state.go()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to use `$state.go` is `$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])`. So, your code will look like

```
$state.go('details', {id: id});
```

and retrieve the id with

```
$stateParams.id
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#state-1